# Is there a 'file indexer' for EVERY file on linux?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, networking, search, search-engines

I'm using winXP and openSUSE...
On win, I have 'search everything' tool, which indexes every file in comp..
Is there a similar tool for linux..
It saves me much time...
Thank you...
http://www.voidtools.com/

Answer (score 3):

For example you can use `updatedb` to create a directory index and search the index with `locate`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -name "*.txt"
```

of course replacing *.txt with whatever you're looking for.

Comment: Doesn't index and is therefore painfully slow with a lot of files.